# Does 'bon marché' have the same connotation of "low quality" as 'cheap' in English

Tags: anglais, usage, sens, comparaison-de-langues

Somehow *bon marché* and *économique* sound positive to me, as some kind of praise. In English *cheap* has a connotation of *not good*. It can be used for an expensive thing but not well made. Am I just mistaken in my impression of *bon marché*, or does it really differ in French and English?

Comment: It seems to be that a good translation into English for *bon marché* would be "a bargain".

Comment: @Jez: I don't think so, *a bargain* would be closer to *une (bonne) affaire*, or maybe to *un (bon) marché* like in “nous avons conclu un (bon) marché”, but as a *noun*, *not* as an adjective.

Comment: I would be actually interested to know how to convey meaning of English 'cheap' in French...

Comment: @Denis: I think *premier prix* or *bas de gamme* could be used for that.

Comment: Je trouve un proverbe sur set sujet aussi "Bon marché tire agent de bourse" c'ai été interesant pour moi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right. Neither *bon marché*  nor  *économique* are used in the same way as *cheap* is used to belittle the quality of the goods.
*Économique* definitely has a connotation of praise, maybe *bon marché* less so but neither is used in a deprecatory way.

Remember though that these words are not really interchangeable.

When you use *économique* you are implicitly saying there are more expensive ways of spending your money.  The point of view is that of the content of your purse. *Économique* is used in the same way as the English "economical".

*Bon marché* is used to qualify the price of the goods.  And of course if you buy something that is *bon marché* it is *économique* for your purse.

*Bon marché* originally was ***à*** bon marché (1171) (meaning you are making a good deal).

By the way, [Le Bon Marché](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_March%C3%A9) was the first French department store.

Comment: Annnnnd that's an impressive answer, (sometimes I just wish I was 50 years older to know my mothertongue). Thanks for all the details I knew I couldn't explicit >_<' (Btw, could the original *(à) bon marché* be rather the marketplace than the deal ?)

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas : Le mot « marché » vient du latin *mercatus* qui désigne une transaction commerciale.
Mais il a d'abord désigné en français une réunion de vendeurs et d'acheteurs et c'est par métonymie que ça a désigné ensuite le lieu où se tient cette réunion et la négociation commerciale en elle-même.
 Je pense personnellement que quand on dit  « à bon marché » on parle plus de la transaction commerciale que du lieu.

Comment: @LaVieuxGildas and Laure: Merci. Maintenant, j'ai la confirmation de mon hypothèse.

Answer (score 3):

In my mind, *bon marché* **is** indeed much more of a praise in French as is 'cheap' in English. You still get what you pay for, but the emphasis is on the money you save, rather than on the poor quality of what you get. The same stands for *économique*.

As you mention it yourself, 'cheap' can be used to describe sheer quality, whatever the price may be, whereas *économique* cannot be used in that sense.

That being said, I'd probably use *bon marché* to translate 'a poor man's (something)' (and I'm not sure what consequences it has :)