# How to say "cheap" in French?

Tags: sens, questions, synonymes, antonyme

In English we can say something is "expensive" or "cheap" (one word adjectives).
In french we say « cher » or « pas cher » (negation of « cher »).

Is there any antonyme to « cher » in one word in French? If not, is there any explication for why a great language like French does not have one word adjective to mean the word "cheap"?

Comment: Did you try looking in a dictionary? This is a great site, but don't just ask questions that can be solved by googling "<word> in French".

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/does-bon-march%C3%A9-have-the-same-connotation-of-low-quality-as-cheap-in-engli) can also be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't any one-word adjective for that.
As for why, I guess saying 'pas cher' isn't difficult enough to create a new word for that. There doesn't seem to be any explicit reason behind that. We just didn't create it.

You can always presume that it is a matter of taboo about buying inexpensive things, but that would be mere speculation.

Comment: You could use; Économique:Avantageux, qui coûte peu.
Exemple : Une voiture économique.

Comment: Yes but it isn't used often... "Pas cher", "Bon marché" are more common IMHO